# python class dict references - avoid duplicate data

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary, memory

I have a question about how Python handles references between classes and objects passed between them. In one particular section of my program I have a reference issue that I'm not sure whether Python is actually referencing the same dict object, or if it is creating a lot of duplicates in memory for each instantiation of the new objects which would be problematic. I'm not sure how to test this either since the object I'm referencing is just a dictionary I can't print it like a class object to see the ID.

Here's a super simplified example of what I'm doing:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, target, items_dict):
        self.target = target
        self.sub_items = []
        self.load_items(items_dict)

    def load_items(self, items_dict):
        target = self.target
        for item in items_dict:
            self.sub_items.append(SubItem(items_dict[item], target))

class SubItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data, target):
        self.attr1 = data['attr1']
        self.attr2 = data['attr2']
        self.target = target

    def mult(self):
        return self.attr1 * self.target['a']

target_to_load = {'a': 1}
items_to_load = {
    'objone': {'attr1': 1, 'attr2': 2},
    'objtwo': {'attr1': 1, 'attr2': 2}
}

new_container = Container(target_to_load, items_to_load)
print new_container.sub_items[0].mult()
```

The way this code is passing the dict to the SubItems, is Python creating actual duplicates of the dictionary data, or is every SubItem going to reference the same dictionary in memory? During a program execution, I may only have three or four unique Targets, but I could have thousands of SubItems, so this could be potentially extremely memory inefficient.

The problem is I don't know if and how to figure out what Python would be doing behind the scenes, but in the event it is duplicating the data, perhaps a more efficient solution would be to pass self to SubItem so SubItem can point to a reference of Container.target:

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, target, items_dict):
        self.target = target
        self.sub_items = []
        self.load_items(items_dict)

    def load_items(self, items_dict):
        target = self.target
        for item in items_dict:
            self.sub_items.append(SubItem(items_dict[item], self))


class SubItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data, container):
        self.attr1 = data['attr1']
        self.attr2 = data['attr2']
        self.target = container.target

    def mult(self):
        return self.attr1 * self.target['a']


target_to_load = {'a': 1}
items_to_load = {
    'objone': {'attr1': 1, 'attr2': 2},
    'objtwo': {'attr1': 1, 'attr2': 2}
}


new_container = Container(target_to_load, items_to_load)
print new_container.sub_items[0].mult()
```

However, I have no idea if this is any more efficient or even necessary, so any enlightenment on more details of the Python backend in this situation would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to test this either since the object I'm referencing is just a dictionary I can't print it like a class object to see the ID." That has nothing to do with "class objects" versus built-in object types. Class objects inherit their `repr` form `object`, which is why they all seem the same, but that is overridable behavior. In any event, you can always use `id(my_object)` if you really want t see if the objects are the same. Or use the `is` operator.

Comment: In any event, in Python, passing objects as arguments or assigning to a name or attribute *never* copies data. Under the hood, it's all `Py_Object` pointers (in CPython, of course). So, if your question is whether `target` gets copied when it is passed as an argument, the answer is no.

Comment: ah, I was unaware of id(). So essentially, I've assigned a namespace to the dictionary with Container.target = target, then when passing this dict to the SubItem class, that is still the same dictionary just being assigned to another name SubItem.target? In that event, if I were to mutate SubItem.target, then Container.target would reflect the same changes?

Comment: You should take a look at Ned Batchelder's (a StackOverflow legend) article on [Facts and Myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Yes, precisely. See the link above. In python, assignment is like putting a nametag on an object. `x = object(); y = x` does not copy `x`, instead, it assigns the same object to two different names.

Comment: Excellent, I've read a handful of these types of articles and had a feeling this was what was happening, but I'm still new enough Python and programming to still be a little confused at times with these types of back-end behaviors. Thanks for the link, I will definitely read it and hopefully completely understand the namespace behavior of python soon!

Comment: But technically, the namespace is not `Container.target`. That's the *classes* namespace. Classes in Python are merely another object. So are functions and modules. Everything defined in the class definition block is in the class namespace, however, if you assign to `self`, e.g. `self.target = target` in a method, then that is the *instances* namespace. It's actually a simple data model, but it's a bit different from other popular class-based OOP systems, like C++ and Java.

Comment: if you have `MyObject` class, and make an instance, `instance = MyObject()`, you can see what belongs to the *class* namespace by using `MyObject.__dict__` and see what belongs to the *instance* by using `instance.__dict__`. The behavior of instances is such that they check their own namespace for an attribute, and if it isn't there, it checks the class namespace. Inheritence is when objects of some child class checks it's parent's class namespaces if it doesn't find the attribute in the class namespace.

Comment: Again, it is very important to keep in mind that *everything* is an object in Python. Even classes, Indeed, classes have their own class, i.e. the metaclass. By default, the metaclass is  `type`, but you can define your own metaclass to change the behavior of how classes get initialized (this can be used for the singlton patter, for example).

Comment: Yes, I do understand the hierarchal namespaces, and by Container.target I was referring to the instance, so I should have written new_container.target to be precise.

So essentially the two methods above are really doing the same thing behind the scenes, just using different names of the same data.

This makes perfect sense now too, why when I save my data out to JSON, I have to do a dict_for_json = new_container.__dict__.copy(), otherwise any modifications to dict_for_json actually changes the class instance new_container!

Thanks again for the clarifications, very helpful!